# How to use dygraphs in Vue.js webapp?

Tags: vuejs2

how to integrate dygraphs library in Vuejs webapp

i used npm wrapper for integration :

```
npm install --save vue-dygraphs
```

and then using:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueDygraphs from 'vue-dygraphs'

Vue.use(VueDygraphs)
```

but i don't know how to integrate them for required graphs in Vuejs

Comment: What have you done besides that?

Comment: I needed the same thing so I looked at the source code of the plugin and it looks incomplete and not ready to be used.